# Pass onlyedited form fields for AJAX PUT request from REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with several fields in it, on `Save` button click it will a trigger an AJAX request to update my data. Currently its only working if I fill all of the fields in the form for update because I'm passing the `$('#field').val()`, but what if I want to only update one of the field? How can I do it without requiring the rest of the field because I'm using this for multiple editing based on which row(s) of data I've selected to update

below is my code :

HTML :

```
    <form id="create_project" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <label>Priority:</label>
                <select id="priority_field">
                    <option selected="selected">Select Your Priority</option>
                    <option value="Low">Low</option>
                    <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                    <option value="High">High</option>
                    <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                </select><br>
            <label>Assign To: </label>
                <select id="assign_to_field" onchange="filter_by_users();">
                    <option selected="selected">Select Your User</option>
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    {% for user in selected_project.user.all %}
                        <option value="{{ user }}">{{ user }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            <br>
            <label> Start Date:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start_date_field"><br>
            <label>Duration:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="duration_field"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer modal_styling">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editForm()">Edit
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
            </button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

javascript :

```
// TASK MULTI EDIT
function editForm(){
    var selected_task = gantt.getSelectedTasks();
    for(var i = 0; i < selected_task.length; i++){
        var task = selected_task[i];
        var data = gantt.getTask(task);
        $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/dashboard/workorder_detail/' + data.workorder_id + '/',
                data: { "id" : data.workorder_id,
                        "priority": $('#priority_field').val(),
                        "assign_to": $('#assign_to_field').val(),
                        "start_date": $('#start_date_field').val(),
                        "duration": $('#duration_field').val(),
                    },
                success: function () {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (err) {
                alert("Failed");
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You should handle it which fields is changed then you can select for sending as parameter on ajax request.
This is listener for which field has changed and add class name of 'has-changed'

```
function changeEvent() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('has-changed'))
        $(this).addClass('has-changed');
}
```

This is set event for inputs

```
$('#create_project input,select').on('change',changeEvent);
```

Then you can select changed fields with below code

```
var postData = {};
    $('#create_project .has-changed').each(function (i,e) {
        var id = $(e).attr('id');
        var value = $(e).val();
        postData[id]=value;

    });
```

after then you add the postData in your ajax 'data' properties like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/api/dashboard/workorder_detail/' + data.workorder_id + '/',
            data: postData,
            success: function () {
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        })
```

**EDIT :**
you should use below code before "editForm" function because this code didn't read from browser before click edit button, you can see it works after click and change any form item and click second time edit button in your code.

```
function changeEvent() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('has-changed'))
            $(this).addClass('has-changed');
    }

$('#edit_form input,select').on('change',changeEvent);

// TASK MULTI EDIT
function editForm(){
    var selected_task = gantt.getSelectedTasks();



    var postData = {};
    $('#edit_form .has-changed').each(function (i,e) {
        var id = $(e).attr('id');
        var value = $(e).val();
        postData[id]=value;

    });
    for(var i = 0; i < selected_task.length; i++){
        var task = selected_task[i];
        var data = gantt.getTask(task);
        $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/dashboard/workorder_detail/' + data.workorder_id + '/',
                data: postData,
                success: function () {
                   // location.reload();
                   console.log(postData);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                alert("Failed");
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Ferhat, thanks a lot for your help, this looks viable, let me implement this in my code and I get back to you in a while

Comment: Yes sure you should use it. @M.Izzat

Comment: Hi again @Ferhat, I add my updated code on top, its not working because apparently `postData` is passing an empty array. i'm sure its an amateur mistake, I'm working on it and I appreaciate if you can give it a looksie

Comment: after further investigation i discovered, that for some reason the data only is only pushed into the `postData` array on second time click the `edit` button, the first time it is pressed will send an empty array

Comment: I already edit your  answer. Sorry i am new on stackoverflow hence i dont know any editing inform to you. So you can see my answer on your last edited code

Comment: Not at all @M.Izzat